# Figure doesn't appear when using multicols

Tags: floats, multicol

I am using following code but unfortunately it doesn't render the `figure` environment. The problem is because of `\begin{multicols}{2}` `\end{multicols}` but I do not know how to resolve it:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy,textcomp,marvosym,picins,amsmath,amsthm,subfigure}
\usepackage{eurosym,mathrsfs,fancyhdr,CJK,multicol,indentfirst,color,bm,upgreek,booktabs}
\usepackage{url,adjustbox,slashbox,amstext}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption, multirow, makecell}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage[noend]{algorithm}
%\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
%\usepackage[lined,algonl,boxed]{algorithm2e}
\looseness=-1
%------------Page layout and margin and Headrule-------------
\headsep=5mm \headheight=4mm \topmargin=0cm \oddsidemargin=-0.5cm
\evensidemargin=-0.5cm \marginparwidth=0pt \marginparsep= 0pt
\marginparpush=0pt \textheight=23.1cm \textwidth=17.5cm \footskip=8mm
\columnsep=7mm \setlength{\doublerulesep}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\footnotesep=3.5mm\arraycolsep=2pt
\font\tenrm=cmr10
%===========================================================
\def\footnoterule{\kern 1mm \hrule width 10cm \kern 2mm}
\def\rmd{{\rm d}} \def\rmi{{\rm i}} \def\rme{{\rm e}}
\def\sj#1{$^{[#1]}$}\def\lt{\left}\def\rt{\right}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\tablename{\bf \footnotesize Table}
\renewcommand\figurename{\footnotesize Fig.\!\!}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}%
\captionsetup[longtable]{labelsep=period}%
\allowdisplaybreaks
\sloppy
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\catcode`@=11
\def\title#1{\vspace{3mm}\begin{flushleft}\vglue-.1cm\Large\bf\boldmath\protect\baselineskip=18pt plus.2pt minus.1pt #1
\end{flushleft}\vspace{1mm} }
\def\author#1{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize #1\end{flushleft}\vspace*{-4pt} \vspace{3mm}}
\def\address#1#2{\begin{flushleft}\vglue-.35cm${}^{#1}$\small\it #2\vglue-.35cm\end{flushleft}\vspace{-2mm}\par}
\def\jz#1#2{{$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny #1}}$\footnotetext{$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny #1}}$#2}}}
\def\jzd#1#2{$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny{#1}}}$\footnotetext{$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny{#1}}}$#2}}
\catcode`@=11
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
 %{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-3ex \@plus -.3ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {2.2ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=14.5pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\bfseries}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
 %{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-3ex\@plus -.2ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {2ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=12.5pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\bfseries}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
 %{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-2.2ex\@plus -.21ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {1.4ex \@plus.2ex}
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=12pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\sl}}
\def\proofname{{\indent \it Proof.}}
%===========================================================ÒÔÉÏ²»¶¯
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Çå¿ÕÒ³Ã¼Ò³½Å
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\sl Shortened Title Within 45 Characters}%
\fancyhead[RO]{\small\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\sl aaa.}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{GBK}{song}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-13mm}
\end{CJK*}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{a.jpg}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{b.jpg}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
 \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{a.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should read the [`multicol`](//ctan.org/pkg/multicol) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf) (section **2.4 Floats inside a `multicols` environment**). Specifically, use `figure*`, not `figure`.

Comment: @Werner That was it

Comment: `\looseness=-1` is a very odd thing to have in the preamble (it just applies to the first paragraph in the document) also why the plain tex declarations such `font\tenrm=cmr10` and `\rm` , `\bf` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because that is the journal's template and I have no power to change anything!

Comment: a journal just gives you a template of bad definitions to put into an `article` class document instead of providing you with a class or package to use? That is very odd.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Very odd but not my fault. [Here](http://jcst.ict.ac.cn/attached/file/20180913/20180913234152_310.zip) it is.

Comment: ouch painful:( but as you say, not your fault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`multicol`](//ctan.org/pkg/multicol) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf) states the following in section **2.4 Floats inside a `multicols` environment**:

> Within the `multicols` environment the usual star float commands are available but their function is somewhat different as in the `twocolumn` mode of standard LaTeX. Stared floats, *e.g.*, `figure*`, denote page wide floats that are handled in a similar fashion as normal floats outside the `multicols` environment. However, they will never show up on the page where they are encountered. In other words, one can influence their placement by specifying a combination of `t`, `b`, and/or `p` in their optional argument, but `h` doesn't work because the first possible place is the top of the next page. One should also note, that this means that their placement behavior is determined by the values of `\topfraction`, *etc.* rather than by `\dbl...`.

So, if you want a (floating) figure to appear, use `figure*`, not `figure`.

Comment: What if someone wants to print a figure in only one column? Any solution?