# Floats in multicol

Tags: floats, multicol

I have learned that [the `multicols` environment is not compatible with floating objects](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458525/figure-doesnt-appear-when-using-multicols) such as figures. One must either use a `figure*` environment or use the parameter `[H]` in `float` package. However, in many journal articles, figures were placed in a single columns and they seems to be floating well (placed in a single column at the top/bottom of a page, breaking the paragraphs). Therefore, I am curious about how it was done. Anyone has an idea? Thanks!

Comment: the standard latex twocolumn mechanism supports single and double column floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's two-column typesetting, a document class can set text in two columns and allow for single-column floats (see, e.g., `ltugboat` or the `twocolumn` option on the standard document classes). The limitation here is that LaTeX will *not* automatically balance columns at the end of the document or a page break. This can be resolved by manually managing the column break during the production phase of producing the journal.

Comment: Thanks! it's working well :)